# Looping through an object and displaying data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, loops, object

I am attempting to pull data from an api an display it to the user. I have made a succesful fetch call and I am looping through the data here in my HomeScreen component.

```
  const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  const [showData, setShowData] = useState();

  const [show, setShow] = useState('Car');
  

  const getShow = () => { 
    fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q='+show)
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((json)=>{

      for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        
      setShowData({
        name: json[i].show.name,
        desc: json[i].show.summary,
        image: json[i].show.image,
      });
    }
      })
    
      .catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error);
      })
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getShow();
  },[])

    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <View style = {styles.container}>
           <ShowDisplay showData={showData} navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
       );
     };
```

But when I attempt to display the data in my 'Show Display' component, I only get the last item displayed. Here is my Show Display component:

```
export default function ShowDisplay({navigation, showData}) {
  if(showData){
       
console.log(showData);

      return(
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.show}onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Shows')}>    
          <View style={styles.text}>
            <Text style={styles.font}>{showData.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            );

  }else{

    return(
         <View>
            <Text>Loading data</Text>
          </View>
          )
}

}
```

As you can see I have created a console.log to see what 'ShowData' was and it was ALL of looped data from the API:

```
Object {
  "desc": "<p>We Brits love our cars but, just like any relationship, sometimes things can get a little rusty. Meet master mechanic Fuzz Townshend and radio and TV presenter Tim Shaw, a petrol-head pair who undertake dramatic automobile interventions across the UK, hoping to return some much-loved motors to their former glory. With a tight deadline to turn each job around without the owners knowing, find out how these neglected classics fell in need of a little loving care – and what Fuzz and Tim can do to get them back on the road.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/100/250748.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/100/250748.jpg",
  },
  "name": "Car S.O.S",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>Join car addict Tyler Hoover as he makes his way across America buying the coolest, hardest to find cars at even harder to find prices. As soon as he scores, he puts his new ride to the test, on race tracks, off-road adventures and road trips through the heartland. Tyler then meets up with his mechanic \"The Wizard,\" to diagnose whether he bought a winner or a loser, and decide whether to keep the car or flip it.</p>",
  "image": null,
  "name": "Car Issues",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>The drivers of exotic supercars put their street cred on the line against deceptively fast sleeper cars built and modified by true gearheads.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/149/374889.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/149/374889.jpg",
  },
  "name": "Fastest Car",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>Funnyman and automotive freak, Adam Carolla, brings you the ultimate car lover's show, featuring awesome cars, epic driving adventures and the best of automotive culture. It's the perfect mix of comedy, shop talk and eye candy brought to you by Adam and his co-hosts, Pulitzer Prize-winning automotive journalist Dan Neil \"TheSmokingTire.com\" founder Matt Farah; and former NBA Champion John Salley.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/57/143804.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/57/143804.jpg",
  },
  "name": "The Car Show",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>Two teams, two cars, 72 hours. That's the basic premise for a new action-packed custom-car competition, <b>Car Warriors</b>, that brings the highest levels of automotive expertise together for a non-stop battle of artistry and craftsmanship. <br><br>Each episode of Car Warriors lets viewers witness the fast-forward creation of custom performance cars by two eight-member teams of top-notch professionals – the Car Warriors All Stars vs. a variety of challenger teams – who take their projects from stripped-down shells to high-performance works of art. <br><br>But there's a catch: each team has just 72 hours from the time they first lay eyes on the primered bodies until they roll out their beautiful custom cars that are ready for judging. That's 72 hours of round-the-clock, high-pressure car building.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/15/39919.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/15/39919.jpg",
  },
  "name": "Car Warriors",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>Presented by Dermot O'Leary, the Saturday night entertainment show, <b>The Getaway Car</b>, will see couples compete in a series of exciting driving challenges that test the limits of their relationships behind the wheel of a car. Can married couples, grandparents and grandchildren, brothers and sisters or best friends work together to scoop the top prize? Or for that matter, will they still be talking afterwards?</p><p>The Getaway Car is packed with thrills, laughter and challenges. At the centre of the show is the fastest driver of his generation: the enigmatic, the iconic, The Stig. Nobody said winning the money would be easy.</p><p>12 x 60 minute episodes have been ordered.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/37/93224.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/37/93224.jpg",
  },
  "name": "The Getaway Car",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>Ichika Tendo is a single mother raising her five year old son alone, while she is assigned to work the doctor car for a general hospital. Unlike an ambulance, the doctor car has a doctor which will use this car to make visits to patients. However Ichika has difficulties with her teamleader Asagi as he wants to get rid of this unit.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/51/128632.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/51/128632.jpg",
  },
  "name": "Doctor Car",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p><b>Car Hunters</b> follows individuals as they passionately search for their dream car. In each episode we follow a new buyer, aided by a friend or family member, as they check out three unique vehicles and hit the open road for a test drive. We share in the exhilaration and deliberation as they try to decide which ride they will cruise home in. Featured buyers include an empty nester who wants to recapture his youth with a car from his glory days; a father and son duo who are on the hunt for a thrill ride to bond over; a former correctional officer looking to kick off his retirement in style by owning a classic convertible; and a life-long lover of iconic low-riders who's looking to finally buy one of his own!</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/55/138960.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/55/138960.jpg",
  },
  "name": "Car Hunters",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>A reality series wherein undercover cops rig a car with cameras and remote control devices and leave it in high crime environments to entice and apprehend car thieves.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/99/248920.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/99/248920.jpg",
  },
  "name": "Bait Car",
}
Object {
  "desc": "<p>In <b>Car Wars</b>, ride along with the UK's only unmarked police force as they take down Greater Manchester's most violent criminals: gangs who use stolen cars for ram raids, burglaries and robberies.</p>",
  "image": Object {
    "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/107/268789.jpg",
    "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/107/268789.jpg",
  },
  "name": "Car Wars",
}
```

But what I get displayed on the screen is this:

[image]

As you can see there is only one show displayed and the console.log shows that there are many shows... How do I display all of them? I think it's because i'm not looping through it but that doesn't work?

So basically I have tried looping it on this page, not looping it on the other page, but to not avial.

What do I need to do to make all the shows show up on the page?

Comment: well, you are setting the state repeatedly and the final state is what gets displayed (all others are set for less than one frame probably). You need to have a state composed of an array of data and display them in a for loop. I'll add a proper answer

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the fetched data and setting each one individually to the state. This means that once the loop has finished only the last item is saved and then shown to the user. Instead, save the entire array of items to the state and then dynamically create a component for each item.

```js
fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=' + show)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const items = json.map(item => ({
      name: json[i].show.name,
      desc: json[i].show.summary,
      image: json[i].show.image
    });
    setShowData(items);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And then in the render function:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  {showData.map(dataItem => (
    <ShowDisplay showData={dataItem} key={dataItem.name} navigation={navigation} />
  ))}
</View>
```

*Note: by doing it this way `showData` will now be an array and not an object. This should be kept in mind, as well as having the default state value be an empty array.*

```
const [showData, setShowData] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component would need to look something similar to the below. The original state for the `showData` variable is an array (`[]`) and then the data is mapped to a list of `ShowDisplay` components. Also, look how each list item has a `key` attribute (which should be unique), like recommended by [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

```typescript
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [showData, setShowData] = useState([])

  const [show, setShow] = useState('Car')

  const getShow = () => {
    fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=' + show)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
          setShowData([
            ...showData,
            {
              name: json[i].show.name,
              desc: json[i].show.summary,
              image: json[i].show.image,
            },
          ])
        }
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getShow()
  }, [])

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {showData.map((data) => (
          <ShowDisplay key={data.name} showData={data} navigation={navigation} />
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```